# Remove common words but when asked to return an understandable content?

Tags: php, algorithm, artificial-intelligence, information-retrieval

I was wondering if somehow (maybe with an aglorithm) a submitted text like the one below can be summarized (removing the common words)

> Scarlet and blue have featured on the club shirt for more than one
>   hundred years and the club is widely known as the ‘Blaugrana’ in
>   reference to the names of these colours in the Catalan language.

but when it is asked, to make use of the saved data and return an understandable content. Maybe not the same but something that you easily understand.

Will this make use of artificial intelligence ? What methods are today that doing this ?

**Update (to clear things up):**
I want to know how does a computer can connect keywords to provide an understandable content. For example `"Scarlet, blue, club, shirt"` to be returned like `"Scarlet and blue are the club shirt"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are 2 different tasks:

1. **Extract** important information.
2. **Generate** meaningful content.

To accomplish both of them you have to use some meaningful text representation between (1) and (2). The best option I can think of is using ontologies. First extract facts from free text and put them into ontology, then generate text from this ontology. Something like [this](http://duc.nist.gov/pubs/2007papers/uhouston.final.pdf). Anyway, you need to extract **facts**, not *keywords*.

Comment: What is used to save these facts and make questions on them? Like the example http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resource_Description_Framework#Example_1:_RDF_Description_of_a_person_named_Eric_Miller.5B15.5D

Comment: Facts are stored in a knowledge base, i.e. in the easiest case database of triplets of <subject, predicate, object>. For example, <Scarlet, is_a, shirt>. Why you want to make questions to the KB? In your original question you need only summarizing text into main facts and generating meaningful content from them. I can't see any reason to make questions here.

Comment: Actually after reading many many articles and understanding some terms, the path I want to read more refers to ontology, Semantic Web and NLP to make questions like this example http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resource_Description_Framework#Example_1:_RDF_Description_of_a_person_named_Eric_Miller.5B15.5D Is this what you are referring with your last reply ?

Comment: Yes, it's what I'm talking about.

Comment: I have accepted your answer. I found a tool called Protege for writing/editing OWL. Is this the most used tool for this situation?

Comment: Protégé is good for constructing ontologies, but not for automatic fact extraction and generating meaningful content. You should pay much more attention to the NLP part.

Comment: What is the language that is used to make questions on OWL ?

Comment: @fiogkos: you're looking at the wrong place. There are many possible ontology representations, and there are many possible languages to query results from them. But you don't need all this stuff, you need ontology only during short time between parsing source text and generating result content. Do not concentrate on ontology, pay more attention to NLP.

Answer (score 0):

The keyword is "Text Summarization".

**Update**: Based on your update, I have expanded my answer. You can store your documents in a text search engine such as Lucene/Elasticsearch and query your keywords (such as "Scarlet, Blue, Club, Shirt" to retrieve the matching documents. Not exactly the "other way round"; but you can build additional domain-specific analysis on the returned results of the query.

Comment: And what about the other way round?

Answer (score 0):

Why do you need this for? it looks like you need compression and not intelligent word removal and restore. Try this:

```
function compress($text)
{
    return base64_encode(gzencode($text));
}
function decompress($text)
{
    return gzdecode(base64_decode($text));
}
```

Comment: Why would you use base64 when you want to compress something?

Comment: This is good, but I want something deeper than this. How does a machine will "think" on how to do what I asked?

Comment: @fiogkos: gzip will compress much better than any intelligent redundant word removal you can come up with.

Comment: @Dani I believe you but compression is not exactly the answer I am looking for...

Comment: Can you exactly explain us what are you trying to do?

Comment: @fiogkos: do you need to use the "summarized" result or its just to save space?

Comment: @alessandro1997 I want to know how does a computer can connect keywords to provide an understandable content. For example "Scarlet, blue, club, shirt" to be returned like "Scarlet and blue are the club shirt"

Comment: @fiogkos: there are a lot of options to connect those, and it doesn't directly relate to the question you asked first.

Comment: @Dani I don't know what section of programming is this, or a term that would help. How is it called?

Comment: @fiogkos: Its called Natural language processing.